# How to identify css inline attribute

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

In the webpage that I'm scraping, there are a lot of titles and I need to identify them to set one value in my database. The problem is that those titles doesn't have a specific ID or Class.

They follow those pattern:

```
<p ALIGN="CENTER"><font face="Arial" SIZE="2">
<a name="tituloivcapituloisecaoii"></a><b>
<span style="text-transform: uppercase">Seção II<br>
DAS ATRIBUIÇÕES DO CONGRESSO NACIONAL</span></b></font></p>


<p ALIGN="CENTER"><font face="Arial" SIZE="2"><a name="tituloivcapituloisecaoiii"></a>
<b><span style="text-transform: uppercase">Seção III<br>
DA CÂMARA DOS DEPUTADOS</span></b></font></p>
```

One attribute that identifies them is: `text-trasform: uppercase`.

How can I check if the `p` contains one title?

That's my current code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.findAll():
    if tag.name in ['a', 'strike']:
      tag.decompose()

allp = soup.findAll('p')
for p in allp:          
   print(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have parsed the html by tag type, you can search within the tags using any defining attribute.  The `text-transform:uppercase` can be used in this case.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find_all("p"):
    if p.span["style"]=="text-transform: uppercase":
        title=p.text
        print(title)

>>>Seção IIDAS ATRIBUIÇÕES DO CONGRESSO NACIONAL
```

This will find all `<p>` tags containing `<span>` tags where `style=="text-transform: uppercase"` and print their associated text.

Comment: It didn't work. I edited my question with my current code to u take a look if there's any problem.  When I follow your suggestion, nothing was returned.

Comment: maybe it's happening because the `text-transform` is an attribute of `span`

Comment: Ok, you are right.  change that to `if p.span["style"]=="text-transform: uppercase":`.  I'll update it in the answer as well.

Comment: now I got it: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Tks for your effort.

Comment: I just did a test on the strings you provided and it works.  This is a different problem.  If you are getting that error, what it means is that there is nothing in the rest of your code to deal with `<p>` tags that don't have `<span>` tags associated with them.  The code above will fix your current problem but you need to account for the fact that not all the tags you search will have a `<span>` tag when you incorperate this into code to search an actual page.  If you include `if p.span != None:` in the top line of your for loop, this will filter out `None` types.

Comment: Awesome!  Good luck on the scraper!